# Product of all the eigenvalues of an endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

So I found this question in a Linear Algebra exam that stated the following:

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $f:V \rightarrow V$ an endomorphism. Explain what is the value of the product of all eigenvalues of $f$ and why.

I know that if an endomorphism has a complex eigenvalue then the conjugate is also an eigenvalue, but I don't really know how to approach this problem. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: With multiplicity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of the eigenvalues is the determinant, since a matrix is similar to an upper triangular matrix.